# Suggestions to simplify and perform the summation of a complicated expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions, special-functions, summation

I have a very complicated expression involving Hermite polynomials of complex variables, exponential and hyperbolic functions. Since it is too long to be pasted here, you can find the expression [here](https://pastebin.com/201Zg7Lp).

```
codestr=Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/201Zg7Lp","String"]
(* Check that the code is safe before evaluating next line *)
ToExpression[codestr]
```

Defines

```
p1[n, a, b, r]
```

Further, on simplification, I need to perform the sum: $\sum_{n=0}^{k} p1[n,a,b,r]$. The function $p1$ specifies the expression as shown in the link. Assume that the variables $a$, $b$, $r$ are all real.

I have been dealing with this problem for several days and so far, I haven't been able to come up with efficient ways to simplify and perform this summation either numerically or analytically. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Ideally, the sum should be upto infinity. However, it is enough to have a finite sum upto a sufficiently large $k$. I tried performing the finite sum on substituting numerical values for $a$, $b$, and $r$ but for large $k$, the summation takes too long to evaluate. My aim is to plot the function $p2[a,b,r]\big\rvert_k=\sum_{n=0}^{k} p1[n,a,b,r]$.

Comment: @rhermans Sure. Sorry about that.

Comment: Symbolic approach: The [Mehler formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Completeness_relation) can be used to sum parts of your expression, have you tried that? Your expression strikes me as a bit odd since it has terms of the form `HermiteH[n,z]*HermiteH[n-1,w]^2/HermiteH[n,w]`, especially the `HermiteH` in the denominator is odd, and I wonder if this is really what you want. Numeric approach: For which values `a`, `b`, `r` is this series supposed to converge? Remember that people here have no idea where your expression comes from.

Comment: Can we assume $r > 0$? (or at least $r \neq 0$?) Any similar constraints available for $a$ and $b$?

Comment: @user293787 Yes, there is a danger with any link, even if not in code. I don't think that's avoided by not offering code. I expect people will check the pastebin content before importing it. But the burden of providing the information necessary to work on the question is on th OP, not on the reader. That includes explicit recipe on how to interpret the off-site data. So I stand by my comment and edit.

Comment: @user293787 I have edited the way to import the code to add an opportunity to look at the code before evaluating it.

Comment: @thorimur Yes, we can assume $r>0$ and $a$, $b$ $\in \mathcal{R}$.